# Pywinauto for changing mutliple tabs for Multiple Windows Tab

Tags: python, windows, ui-automation, pywinauto

Can anyone help me on how to switch the tab once the ethernet properties popped up and can select proper combo list. I need to select Sharing tab as shown on the screenshot.

Thanks in Advance !!

Code as below :

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pywinauto,time,keyboard
from pywinauto import Application
from pywinauto.keyboard import send_keys

# Open "Control Panel"
Application().start('control.exe')
app = Application(backend='uia').connect(path='explorer.exe', title='Control Panel')

# Go to "Programs"

app.window(title="Control Panel").NetworkandInternetHyperlink.invoke()
app.wait_cpu_usage_lower(threshold=0.5, timeout=30, usage_interval=1.0)

# Go to "Installed Updates"

app.window(title='Network and Internet').child_window(title='View network status and tasks', control_type='Hyperlink').invoke()
app.wait_cpu_usage_lower(threshold=0.5, timeout=30, usage_interval=1.0)
app.window(title="Network and Sharing Center").ChangeadaptersettingsHyperlink.invoke()

list_box = app.NetworkConnections.FolderViewListBox

# list all updates
items = list_box.descendants(control_type='ListItem')
all_updates = [item.window_text() for item in items]
print('\nAll updates ({}):\n'.format(len(all_updates)))
print(all_updates)

# list updates from "Microsoft Windows" group only
app.window(title='Network Connections').EthernetHyperlink.invoke()
app.Ethernet_Properties.TabControlNetworking.select("Authentication")
dlp = app.top_window()
dlp.type_keys('ctrl+tab')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkZBC.png)

Answer (score 0):

You must run the following Python code with administrator rights:

```
import pywinauto
desktop = pywinauto.Desktop(backend="uia")
window = desktop.windows(title="Control Panel\\All Control Panel Items\\Network Connections", control_type="Window")[0]
sharing_tab = window.descendants(title="Sharing", control_type="TabItem")[0]
sharing_tab.click_input()
```

I pressed CTRL+SHIFT+f in [Pywinauto recorder](https://pywinauto-recorder.readthedocs.io/) to easily identify the element.

Comment: Hi @David , Thanks for your prompt response but it is not working with above code with admin rights. Screenshot is for your reference.

Comment: C:\Users\subas\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/subas/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/pyauto2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\subas\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\pyauto2.py", line 3, in <module>
    window = desktop.windows(title="Control Panel\\All Control Panel Items\\Network Connections", control_type="Window")[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1